# Minhag and nusach differences between Mizrahim and Sephardim (as in OG from Spain/Portugal)

Tags: minhag, nuschaot

These days, it seems the term "Sephardi/Sephardic" simply refers to non-Ashkenazi Jews. However, since Greece, Balkans, and of course Spain and Portugal are a long way from Iran, Iraq, Egypt, it leaves me wondering: what are the differences between the first group and the latter one? How would practices differ between a Jew from Salonika (who presumably traces his roots to Spain) vs a Jew in Tehran?

Also, a rabbi mentioned to me that the differences could be said to be "Sefard vs Sefardi??" IDK if I misheard him or what.

Comment: If it helps to clarify, Nusach Sefard is a modified version of Nusach Ashkenaz. Nusach Edot HaMizrach is the standard Nusach prayed by Sepharadic Jews today, but, as its name implies, of Eastern origin.

Comment: Also, did you see this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach#Sephardi_and_Mizrachi_nuschaot

Comment: What do you mean by "OG"?

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musta%27arabi_Jews

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two nusachot would be the absence of any Lurianic additions in the Spanish-Portuguese rite.

After the incident with the false messiah [Shabbatai Zevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi), who used [Lurianic kabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lurianic_Kabbalah) to deceive people and justify abolishing certain mitzvot (such as brit milah), the Spanish-Portuguese communities removed any kabbalistic additions to the siddur.

Siddurim in Mizrahi communties however continue to include these emendations based on kabbalah, and never removed them from the text.

Comment: Although I don't know their siddurim in detail, I'm not 100% sure, especially after the Chida's siddur. Do you have any sources?

Comment: Kazi bacsi is right sepharadic sidurim from Italia, Maroco and Alger are generally following Arizal

Comment: @kouty And how does that contradict what I said? I said _Spanish-Portuguese_ siddurim removed the kabbalistic emendations, not Moroccan, Italian, etc.

Comment: The Portuguese and Spanish community were not in Portugal, but paritally in Livorno in Marocco, in Holland, in England, in Turkey

Comment: But anyway this communities were edot hamaarav